Publish app update using Microsoft Store Services
Using the Microsoft Store Services API, I have been able to create a submission, upload the application package, and commit the submission using the endpoint described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/commit-an-app-submission
I do not want this package to be published to users automatically, but instead to push it out when I am ready (equivalent to clicking "Publish now" in the Web UI).
I can't see a way to do this in the API documentation. There are several pages dedicated to performing a gradual rollout, but this is unnecessary for my purposes. Is there a "Publish now" endpoint, or is this just missing from the API?
